# query form data to be passed on

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a SQL table structured that way:

```
Id_value    |   id_group_value      |   name_group_value    |   name_value
```

I build a php/sql query to create a dropdown form getting its values which work like that:

```
<label>item</label>             
<?php
$result = $conn->query("select id_ value,id_ group _ value, name _ group_ value, name_value FROM table WHERE id_ group _ value = 0");

echo "<select name='name_value' ><option value='' disabled selected>choose value</option>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        unset($idv, $namev);
        $idv = $row['id_value'];
        $namev = $row['name_value']; 
        $id_gv = $row['id_group_value'];
        $id_v = $row[' name_group_value '];                                 
        echo '<option value="'.$ idv.'">'.$namev.'</option>';

                                }

echo "</select>";
```

I can easily save values from that select form item using a '$_POST[form_item]' which I do this way and means get the $idv variable:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (form_select_value)

VALUES ('$_POST[name_value]')";
```

What should I do to save another extracted value which I retrieved from the original SQL query, let’s say $namev variable, together?

Comment: I having trouble understanding what you mean, could you try to be more precise? Also, your code is open to SQL injections.

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt of course I did not included and should be added to SQL table, thanks for your clarification

Comment: @rpm192 basically I just want to save in another table the data from two of the original columns.

Comment: So in two tables at once?

Comment: @rpm192 no, sorry for being a bit easy on that. The data coming from the original table should pass two of its columns values to the saving action.

Answer (score 0):

Using hidden fields you can set all the values like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nvalue" value="<?php echo $namev; ?>>"
```

And insert value like this,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (form_select_value1,form_select_value2) VALUES ($_POST['name_value'],$_POST['nvalue'])";
```

Comment: I neither thought about such easy solution. A bit long but clearly neither to test, it would certainly work ok. Thanks for that!